# Where I can see more examples of Effects in Mage: The Ascension?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I'm not very good creating my effects myself. Is there any place to discuss about effects in Mage 20 or a book I should read?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is closed a shopping/recommendation, since the question is about one game in particular and where it can be discussed. Is the latter too open?

Comment: @okeefe it looks like they're asking for other sites, not something we do here, the "and other recommendation requests" portion of the close reason are in play.

Comment: Barba if you've got specific questions about effects, we can totally answer those here.

Answer (score 3):

The recent M20 supplement [How Do You DO That?](http://drivethrurpg.com/product/162241/M20-How-Do-You-DO-That) is the new, canonical bible of Mage effects. It's great; I can't recommend it more highly.  (I wish it existed when I first got into Mage.)  The preview at DriveThruRPG has the Table of Contents but unfortunately no solid examples.

Before that supplement came out, players generally would discuss (and argue) about effects on the [Mage forums](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-classic-world-of-darkness/mage-the-ascension).